# Webp changes colour

Tags: c#, webp, imagesharp

Does anybody of you know if there is something happening when changing the format of an image to webp? We have the situation here that it looses colour when being converted from jpg or png to webp.
We are using ImageSharp.

```
public static string? GetOptimisedCropUrl(this IPublishedContent? image, string crop, bool convertWebp=true) {
        if (image == null) {
            return null;
        }

        var webpAppendix = "&format=webp&orient=false";
        if (!convertWebp) {
            webpAppendix = "&format=jpg&quality=80";
        }
        
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(crop)) return image.GetCropUrl(crop) + webpAppendix;
        
        var imageHeight = image.GetProperty("height")?.GetValue()?.SafeCast<int>();
        var imageWidth = image.GetProperty("width")?.GetValue()?.SafeCast<int>();

        if (imageHeight is >= 1440 && imageWidth is >= 2560) {
            return image.GetCropUrl("LargeImageCrop") + webpAppendix;
        }
        return image.Url() + "?width=" + imageWidth + "&height=" + imageHeight + webpAppendix;
    }
```

Comment: You can supply quality to `webp` as well, perhaps setting that to 100 might help

Comment: Unlikely to be issues with png but CMYK jpegs might change color. Not enough info to determine - diagnosis though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but I found enabling the WEBP encoder's `use-sharp-yuv` option helped to keep my colours intense and well saturated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887687/99777